# Gimp exports: Why is the image size increased?

Tags: image-processing, gimp

I'm trying to use a two step process of employing Gimp to delete sections of images and then using Inkscape for the remainder of the image work.

Unfortunately, I'm seeing a resolution change when doing the export to PNG from Gimp.

The exported image is around 50% larger than the original, which impacts the quality.

Is there a way to keep the resolution constant when exporting the file?

Hopefully I'm just forgetting something, since I've spent some time away from image work.

Please let me know if any additional info is required.

In the interim, I'll try another tool to do the Gimp step.

THANKS!

Edit: Updated size to resolution.

Comment: what do you mean with size change? resolution? memory? what is your input format?

Comment: The resolution; the height and width are 50% larger after the save. The format was jpeg and is being exported to PNG.

Comment: what is viewing size? height and width in pixels?

Comment: I'm checking to see what the actual pixel changes are.

Comment: 1053x527 (Gimp xcf) is changed to 1404x703 (Gimp PNG export).

Comment: you just said you saved jpeg as png. now you say you save xcf as png... what is it?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help! Sorry for any confusion. I mentioned JPEG because the original image was JPEG. JPEG into Gimp and then it's being exported to PNG, though it's converted into xcf in Gimp. Then it's exported into PNG. I'll check to see if the xcf save has any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bitmap/raster image, resolution (for Gimp: "Image print resolution", see `Image>Print size`) is **indicative**. The only thing that counts is the size in pixels.

If you have image window set to "Dot for Dot" (`Edit>Preferences>Image Windows->General>"Use dot for dot"` or `View>Dot for dot`) the image is displayed with the definition of your screen (around 100PPI fore regular screens, 20OPPI for high def ones (Retina, etc...).

When you create the image (`File>New...`), you can specify a print definition and a print size, and Gimp will compute the required size in pixels.

Comment: Thanks xenoid! That's the Gimp functionality that I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, I'll close the question after testing.